# Why does rearranging imports cause compilation to fail?

Tags: java, import

Why may re-arranging Java imports cause the code to no longer compile?

I thought that the order of Java imports was not significant to the the semantics of the code making it a safe operation.  Editors make it really easy to organize/optimize/rearrange Java import statements and some style checking/analysis tools will enforce an order.  I am not successfully finding posts online mentioning the dangers of rearranging imports.  However, I have now encountered a case where rearranging the imports causes the code to break.

The following code will not compile saying it cannot find the symbol `Retention`:

```
package foo;
import foo.BadImportsTest.TestOptions.Option;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public final class BadImportsTest {
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface TestOptions {
    enum Option {
      BAR,
      BAZ,
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void DoTest() {
    Assert.assertNotEquals(Option.BAR, Option.BAZ);
  }
}
```

However, in its original order with the first import (`foo.BadImportsTest.TestOptions.Option`) last, it does compile.

I tried checking the spec.  It seems like this is a *Single-Type-Import Declaration* but my reading of [section 7.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1) does is not explaining the above behavior.  I am importing a nested type in the current file, however, it that would cause an issue with anything it would seem it should error on finding `Option` since:

> If the type imported by the single-type-import declaration is declared in the compilation unit that contains the `import` declaration, the `import` declaration is ignored.

I tested compilation both via Maven and IntelliJ IDEA, targeting Java 8 in all cases.

I did find [Order of imports seems to matter for compilation to succeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26520832/1072626) but that points to a compiler bug that would seem not to apply because it concerned `static` imports and I am not using static imports.  Additionally, it is marked as fixed in Java 8 and I am using Java 8.

Comment: **Remove** `import foo.BadImportsTest.TestOptions.Option;` - don't try and `import` something from the class you are **currently in**!

Comment: In which case I need to qualify the usage and then the IDE "helpfully" suggests I import it instead :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6391197

The below code still gives me an error.

```
package test;

import static test.Outer.Inner.CONST;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Outer {
  interface Inner extends Iterator {
    static String CONST = "CONST";
  }
}
```

The bug still exists in java 8, atleast in my compiler version : javac 1.8.0_121.

Java 8 relevant bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8148472

So this is a bug, go for the workaround.

Comment: I wonder why they say the compiler needs to know the type at the moment of import? It seems to me that i only needs to know that the name exists at that point, and be prepared to open its scope, know its type, etc., on demand.

Comment: It indeed seems to be a compiler bug.  I tried Java 6 through Java 10 and my original example starts working with Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it cannot find the retention import because the import 'foo.BadImportsTest.TestOptions.Option;' is importing something from the same class it is in. By putting that import first, you cause the importing process to fail before anything can import. By putting it last, its failure cannot prevent any other imports from failing because they have already been inputted, thus not producing the error you receive if you put it first.